# Raw INNER JOIN REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I use django raw in django rest framework, but using INNER join, I have the following serialized

```
class PcprovinciaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pcprovincia
        fields ="__all__"

class LolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pcprovincia.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PcprovinciaSerializer
    module = "lol"

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
           queryset = self.queryset.raw("SELECT * FROM PCProvincia INNER JOIN PCPais ON idpais=idpais")
           serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
           return Response(serializer.data)
       except Exception as e:
           return Response({"error":str(e)})
```

it generates the following error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Q5G.png)

HOW CAN I SERIALIZE THE INNER JOIN?